# Is it possible to create an Object in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to create an object in Twig?
I want to reach an Object to a twig extension like the following code:

```
{{myFunction({title: titleString, name: nameString})}}
```

I need an Object inside the function.
Unfortunately what I reach to the function here is an array, not an Object.

How can I create an Object in Twig.

If thats not possible how would I reach that array in the function as an object, if the function itself expects an Object as argument?

Comment: Not sure why u want to do this? Whats the advantages of passing an object instead of an array?

Comment: I want to use a function which expects an Object as argument. This function is already in use somewhere. So instead of writing another function which parses an array into an object, it would be simpler to just write an object in twig instead writing an array like above, as I expected that the syntax would be very similar. However as my yet unanswered core question, it seems to not be possible to create an Object in Twig directly.

Comment: In vanilla `twig` it is not possible no, but the answer of Abdelhafid El Kadiri should aid you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a filter to parse arrays to objects as follows :

create an extension for example in src\AppBundle\Twig\Parsers.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class Parsers extends \Twig_Extension {

public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('toObject', array($this, 'toObject')),
    );
}

/**
 * @param array $array
 * @return object
 */
public function toObject($array)
{
    return (object) $array;
}

}
```

if you are using symfony 3.4 with autowiring everything should be working now, 
if you are using 2.8 then register your extension in services.yml with :

```
    app.twig_parsers_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\Parsers
        tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

call the filter in twig :

```
{{myFunction({title: titleString, name: nameString}|toObject)}}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Why not create an alternative function call that will require array and then convert this array to object and run your main function?